# How to let pictureboxes not overlap with each other?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I made a game for a school project in windows forms. Only problem is, is that my pictures are overlapping with each other. So my question how do I get them all on a different location where they don't touch each other or not overlap?

In this Method I create the zombies and here I just choose for random locations between -100 and 0 on the x-as

```cs
public void ZombieMaker(int aantal, Form formInstance, string ZombieDik)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
    {
            PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();

            picture.Image = Properties.Resources.ZombieDik;
            picture.Size = new Size(200, 200);
            picture.Location = new Point(random.Next(1500), random.Next(-100,0));
            picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            picture.Click += zombie_Click;
            picture.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            formInstance.Controls.Add(picture);
            picture.Tag = zombies[i];
    }
}
```

[pic of zombies overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK4r2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the already placed pictureboxes, and validate if the bound would overlap.

```
//List of all pictureBoxes
private List<PictureBox> _pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

public void ZombieMaker(int aantal, Form formInstance, string ZombieDik)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
    {
        Rectangle newPosition;

        //loop till you found a new position
        while (true)
        {
            var newPoint = new Point(random.Next(1500), random.Next(-100,0));
            var newSize = new Size(200, 200);

            newPosition = new Rectangle(newPoint, newSize);

            //validate the newPosition
            if (!_pictureBoxes.Any(x => x.Bounds.IntersectsWith(newPosition)))
            {
                //break the loop when there isn't an overlapping rectangle found
                break;
            }
        }

        PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
        _pictureBoxes.Add(picture);
 
        picture.Image = Properties.Resources.ZombieDik;
        picture.Size = newPosition.Size;
        picture.Location = newPosition.Location;
        ...
      
    }
}
```

To validate the overlapping I am using the `IntersectWith` method of the `Rectangle` class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?view=net-6.0#system-drawing-rectangle-intersectswith(system-drawing-rectangle)

**Edit:**

Here a `do/while` loop instead of the `while` loop.

```
Rectangle newPosition;

do
{
    var newPoint = new Point(random.Next(1500), random.Next(-100,0));
    var newSize = new Size(200, 200);

    newPosition = new Rectangle(newPoint, newSize);
} while(_pictureBoxes.Any(x => x.Bounds.IntersectsWith(newPosition))
```

Comment: `_pictureBoxes.Add(newPosition);` should be `_pictureBoxes.Add(picture);`.  Also, IMHO, it'd look nicer if you use a `do { } while( );` instead of a `while ( ) { }`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind fixed the code, thanks

Comment: Using this code my application(game) freezes when I click all the zombies away. When it should spawn new zombies?

Comment: @Meadas - on clicking the zombies away, do you remove the entries from the list? so do you call `_pictureBoxes.Remove(picture);` - I guess your game freezes because there is no free space to place the next zombie

Comment: I use ``` _pictureBoxes.Clear(); ``` and make new zombies, should it be what you said or should I be able to use this?

Comment: @Meadas - can’t really give an answer to this, depends if you need to remove them one by one, or if you need to remove them all - so eg. if you click on one zombie and this one should be removed than use the .Remove method if you click a button that removes all zombies use the Clear method

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code so the picture boxes do not overlap each other:

```
public void ZombieMaker(int aantal, Form formInstance, string ZombieDik)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
   {
        PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();

        picture.Image = Properties.Resources.ZombieDik;
        picture.Size = new Size(200, 200);
        picture.Location = new Point(picture.Width * i, random.Next(-100,0));
        picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        picture.Click += zombie_Click;
        picture.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        formInstance.Controls.Add(picture);
        picture.Tag = zombies[i];
  }
}
```